# How to iterate over an array of files and change parts of their name before uploading? AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm trying to change part of file names, while iterating over them in an array,as they are being uploaded with AJAX. How can I change the file name(s) before appending it to a FormData() object?

I tried to create a variable inside of a for statement, and then I added a math random function, and substring -- that would prepend a defined string and then add a randomized code to it. The file itself will have 3 parts. "code-" + "randomString" + "-" + "fileName".

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#fileButton").click(function () {
            var files = $("#fileInput").get(0).files;
            var fileData = new FormData();



            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var newFileName = files[i].filename + "code-" + Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
                fileData.append("fileInput", files[i]);
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/AjaxFileUpload/UploadFiles",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false, 
                data: fileData,
                success: function (result, status, xhr) {

                    var fileObj = "<p>" + JSON.stringify(result).replace(/[\[\]"]+/g, "") + "</p>";

                    $("#fileUploadStatus").append(fileObj);
                    $("#fileModal").modal("show");


                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(status);
                }
            });
        });

        $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
            $("#loadingImg").show();
            $("#fileButton").prop('disabled', true);
        });

        $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
            $("#loadingImg").hide();
            $("#fileButton").prop('disabled', false);
            $("#fileInput").val("");
        });

    });
</script>
```

After clicking the file select button and pressing upload. The file name should change before being uploaded to the file folder path. And, then a modal should appear to confirm the file upload was successful.

Comment: seem to be missing `files[i].filename = newFileName`. Currently when you append the file...it still has original name

Comment: Can you give a complete answer and explain your solution?

Comment: right now the new file name is only being applied to a variable (var newFileName) then forgotten. right before `fileData.append("fileInput", files[i]);` add charlietfl's suggestion.